# Integers expressible in the form $x^2 + 3y^2$ 

Tags: number-theory

First of all, I am very thankful to this site. I just came to know this site by google. I have seen some number theory question on this site. The discussion between learner and author is quite good and interesting. I would like to know the proof of following questions. If any one answered, I am very grateful of them.

1. Every prime of the form $3k+1$ is expressible as $u^2 + 3v^2$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$ in precisely one way.
2. The general primitive solution in integers of the equation $x^2 + 3y^2 = N^3$ for odd $N$ is given by $x = u(u^2 - 9v^2)$ and $y = 3v(u^2 - v^2)$ where $u$ and $v$ are co-prime integers.
3. If an integer is representable in the form $a^2 + 3b^2$ with $\gcd(a,3b)=1$, then its only odd prime factors are of the form $p = 3k+1$.

Once again thanks for all team members of this site.

Comment: In your first question, what is $a$ and $b$? You are only talking about a prime $p$ and some integers $u,v$

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If $p$ is odd and prime and not $3k+1$, what is it? and what would the implications be of such a prime dividing $a^2+3b^2$? in particular, what would it say about the quadratic character of $-3$? Have you seen the analogous theorems proved for $u^2+v^2$ and primes $p=4k+1$? If so, can you see how to tweak them to the current situation?

Comment: yes, I tried. But, I couldn't get.

Comment: See also this [related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/is-every-mersenne-prime-of-the-form-x23-cdot-y2)

Answer (score 12):

Your questions are actually a special case of a fascinating topic in number theory, already studied by Euler and Lagrange. "Primes of the form x^2+ky^2" by David Cox is a very good reference on the subject. Now to answer your questions : let $Q(x,y)=x^2+3y^2$.

Lemma 1. Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then $-3$ is a square modulo $p$ iff $p$
is congruent to 1 modulo 3.

Proof of lemma 1. $-3$ is a square iff $x^2+3$ has a root iff $y^2-y+1$ has a root
(set $y=\frac{x+1}{2}$). Now $y^2-y+1$ is the sixth cyclotomic polynomial. So $-3$
will be a square iff a primitive sixth root of unity exists in ${\mathbb Z}_p$, iff some 
element in ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ has (multiplicative) order $6$, iff 6 divides the order of ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ (because  ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ is cyclic). Now the order of ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ is exactly $p-1$, so that this amounts to $p \equiv 1 \ ({\rm mod} \ 6)$ as desired.

Now we can show §3. Let $p$ be an odd prime diving $a^2+3b^2$ with
${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$. Then $p$ is coprime to both $a$ and $b$, so $\frac{a}{b}$ exists in
${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ and it is a square root of $-3$. By lemma 1, we have
that $p \equiv 1 \ ({\rm mod} \ 3)$ as wished.

Lemma 2. Let $N$ be a integer of the form $Q(x,y)$. If $2$ divides $N$,
then $\frac{N}{4}$ is also an integer of the form $Q(x,y)$. If a prime $p=Q(x_0,y_0)$ divides $N$ then $\frac{N}{p}$ is also an integer of the form $Q(x,y)$.

Proof of lemma 2. Suppose that $2$ divides $N=Q(a,b)$. Then $a$ and $b$
are both even or both odd. If they are both even then 
$\frac{N}{4}=Q(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2})$. If they are both odd then either
$a \equiv b \ ({\rm mod} \ 4)$ or $a \equiv -b \ ({\rm mod} \ 4)$. In the first case we have $\frac{N}{4}=Q(\frac{a+3b}{4},\frac{a-b}{4})$ and in the second we have $\frac{N}{4}=Q(\frac{a-3b}{4},\frac{a+b}{4})$.
  Now suppose that a prime $p=Q(x_0,y_0)$ divides $N=Q(a,b)$. The
product $(-y_0a+x_0b)(-y_0a-x_0b)=y_0^2a^2-x_0^2b^2$ is $0$ modulo $p$, so
(replacing $b$ with $-b$ if needed) we may assume that $-y_0a+x_0b \equiv 0 \ ({\rm mod} \ p)$. Set $a'=\frac{x_0a+3y_0b}{p}$ and $b'=\frac{-y_0a+x_0b}{p}$. Then $a'$ and $b'$ are both integers and $\frac{N}{p}=Q(a',b')$. This finishes the proof of lemma 2.

Let us now show §1, by induction on $p$. Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p \equiv 1 \ ({\rm mod} \ 3)$. Then there is a $v$ with $v^2 \equiv -3 \ ({\rm mod} \ p)$ by lemma $1$. So $p$ divides $N=v^2+3\times 1^2$, and by §3 all the primes factors of $N$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ (or equal to $2$). So by the induction hypothesis, all those primes are of the form $Q(x,y)$. Using lemma 2 several times, we can remove all the factors in $N$ other than $p$ and we finally obtain that $p$ is of the form $Q(x,y)$.
  This decomposition is unique up to signs, because if $p=Q(x,y)=Q(x',y')$, then (as in the proof of lemma 2), we may assume that $-yx'+xy' \equiv 0 \ ({\rm mod} \ p)$. Set $a'=\frac{xx'+3yy'}{p}$ and $b'=\frac{-yx'+xy'}{p}$. Then $a'$ and $b'$
are both integers and $1=Q(a',b')$, so $a'=\pm 1, b'=0$ and hence
$x'=\pm x, y'=\pm y$.

Lemma 3. Any product of integers of the form $Q(x,y)$ is again of this form.

Proof of lemma 3. $Q(x,y)Q(x',y')=Q(xx'-3yy',xy'+yx')$ (multiplicativity of norms).

Finally, let us show §2. If $N=Q(x,y)$ is odd then all its prime factors are odd, so by §3they are all congruent to $1$ modulo $3$. Then by §1 they are all of the form $Q(x,y)$. So their product is also of this form by lemma 3 : $N=Q(u,v)$. We deduce $N^2=Q(u,v)Q(u,v)=Q(u^2-3v^2,2uv)$ and 
$N^3=Q(u,v)Q(u^2-3v^2,2uv)=Q(u(u^2-3v^2)-3v(2uv),v(u^2-3v^2)+u(2uv))=
Q(u(u^2-9v^2),3v(u^2-v^2))$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for a prime number $p\ne3$ the following are equivalent:

1. $p\equiv1\pmod3$.
2. $p$ splits in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$, where $\zeta_3=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity.
3. $x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod p$ has a solution (equivalently, $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=1$)
4. $p=x^2+xy+y^2=(x-y\zeta_3)(x-y\zeta_3^2)$ for some integers $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Now for a prime $p\equiv1\pmod3$, let $p=x^2+xy+y^2$. If $x$ is even, $p=(y+\frac x2)^2+3(\frac x2)^2$, so we are done. The same holds for when $y$ is even. If both $x$ and $y$ are odd, $p=(\frac{x-y}2)^2+3(\frac{x+y}2)^2$.

---

**P.S.** 1$\iff$2: $p\ne3$ so $p$ is unramified in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)/\mathbb Q$. Let $P\subseteq\mathbb Z[\zeta_3]=\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)}$ be a prime ideal lying above $p$. The prime $p$ splits completely iff the decomposition group $D_p\cong Gal((\mathbb Z[\zeta_3]/P)/\mathbb F_p)$ is trivial. It is generated by the Frobenius element $\zeta_3\mapsto\zeta_3^p$, so this is trivial iff $\zeta_3^p=\zeta_3$, or, $p\equiv1\pmod 3$.

2$\iff$3: Because $\mathbb Z[\zeta_3]/(p)=\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^2+x+1)$.

1$\iff$3: Because $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is cyclic of order $p$, the field $\mathbb F_p $ has a primitive $3$rd unity iff $3|p-1$. Alternatively, by quadratic reciprocity $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac p3\right)$.

2$\implies$4: $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$ has class number $1$, so let $p=q_1q_2$ for $q_1,q_2\in\mathbb Z[\zeta_3]$ prime. Then the norm is $p^2=N(q_1)N(q_2)$, so $N(q_1)=N(q_2)=p$.

4$\implies$2: $N(x-\zeta_3y)=N(x-\zeta_3^2y)=p$ so $x-\zeta_3y$ and $x-\zeta_3^2y$ are prime. Thus $p=(x-\zeta_3y)(x-\zeta_3^2y)$ is a decomposition.