# Does anyone know of a proof for $a^2+3b^2=p$ where $p=3k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that every prime $p>3$ which satisfies $p=3k+1$ can be written as $a^2+3b^2$. Does anyone know of a comprehensive proof of this result?

Comment: The assumption $p>3$ is unnecessary when $p=3k+1$.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76878/integers-expressible-in-the-form-x2-3y2

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity implies that the condition is necessary.

Comment: If $3k+1$ is not prime, but all its prime factors have that form,  then it can be written as $a^2+3b^2$ in more than one way. E.g. $217=5^2+3(8^2)=13^2+3(4^2)$, and $247=2^2+3(9^2)=10^2+3(7^2)$. So primality seems to be a sufficient but not necessary condition for $3k+1=a^2+3b^2$.